# Margin/Padding of ViewGroup ignored on api 19. Works only when set programmatically and view gets recycled

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-constraintlayout

I successfully include a constraint layout in another layout. But this only works when I'm running an API greater than 19. On all devices using API 19, the margin and padding values of the included constraintlayout are ignored, which completely puzzles the resulting layout.

Is there any limitation to layout include on API 19 and below? As I already said, everythign works fine when dealing with API > 19.

Following is the xml code which I want to include:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                         android:id="@+id/cardBack"
                                         android:layout_width="@dimen/card_width_shop"
                                         android:layout_height="@dimen/card_height_shop"
                                         android:layout_gravity="center"
                                         android:background="@drawable/card_bg_black"
                                         android:padding="@dimen/card_back_padding">
```

In the Android Studio designer everything looks perfectly fine (padding is working):
[image]

I already tried:
- replacing the padding reference with 15dp - still not working.
- removing the padding attribute and set margin for the children of the layout where nessessary - still not working.
- wrapping the layout inside of a RelativeLayout and passing the padding to this layout - still not working.
- replacing the include tag with the xml of the original xml file - still not working. So it seems this problem doesn't have anything to do with the include tag.
- replacing the ConstraintLayout with a RelativeLayout - still not working.
- setting padding programmatically - only works AFTER view is recycled (in GridView). Every other use: still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for some strange reason, it works when I remove the padding completely and set margin for the children respectively.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Use this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/def_user"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/def_user"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/def_user"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/def_user"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Add :**

> or you can use this hierarchy :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" // you can use margin for ConstraintLayout , in this case you will have a space between constraintLayout and relative layout
    >

<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp" // or you can use padding for relativeLayout and you will have space between images and parent(RelativeLayout)
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/def_user"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/def_user"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/def_user"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/def_user"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I wrapped the ConstraintLayout inside of the RelativeLayout and passed the padding to it, but the padding is still ignored by the ConstraintLayout's childs.

Comment: so use the design part of android studio and fix the components according to parents

Comment: I already did, that's the problem. In the android designer and on all devices running API > 19 the layout works as intended and as shown in the designer of Android Studio.

Comment: Can I see what you want to do ? add a screen or the XML code to your question!!

Comment: added a screenshot of the design tool.

Comment: I edited the answer for you try it and keep me updated

Comment: I replaced the ConstraintLayout with a RelativeLayout. Again, in the designer everything looked fine. But even when using a RelativeLayout instead of a ConstraintLayout, my padding is ignored.

Comment: I tried setting the padding programmatically by calling setPadding() in the getView method of my gridview adapter. The first time the view is created, there is still no padding. When I scroll the view out of the display and back in, the padding is added as expected (only when using setPadding).

Comment: check the second code in my answer I used `ConstraintLayout` with `RelativeLayout`

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it still doesn't work... :( There has to be some problem with Android 4.4 I guess. For now, I raised my minSDKVersion to 21 to eliminate the problem, until I can find a suitable solution.

Comment: Okay, something weird just happened. I was playing around with my initial layout and removed the padding of the wrapping layout. Next, I set the margin of the childviews, e.g. marginStart="myOriginalPadding". Et voilá! It works.

Comment: I said weird, because I already tried this when I first started this discussion and back then, this definitly didn't work..